# Service/Product to enable users on my Web App to invite friends (e.g. Hotmail, Yahoo Messenger, Gmail, AIM, etc)

Tags: web-applications, yahoo, aim

I'm building a consumer web application and want to enable my users to invite their friends/contacts from popular email (e.g gmail, yahoo, hotmail) and social networking services to join my service.  Can you suggests some products/services you've used in the past that enable this sort of functionality.  Can you tell me what you like/don't like about the product/service.  Thx in advance for the help!

Comment: This forum is dedicated to programming questions and answers. Since you are asking about a product to do this, and not help in doing it programmatically, this question is off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

A simple widget can be ["ShareThis"](http://sharethis.com/)